# Error when Submitting a list of an objective

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5, submitchanges

I got this error when I go to submit the object from a list in MVC 5, and it is always happening in the second item of list

I use this to call the database method;

```
foreach (var modulo in _Modulos)
{
    USERS_MODULO _modulo = new USERS_MODULO();
    _modulo = modulo;
    _modulo.USUARIO = usuario;
    _PermissoesLinxDB.SalvaModulosUser(_modulo);
    _modulo = null; 
}
```

> Line 86:         { Line 87:             DBRetaguardDataContext
>   dbRetaguard = new DBRetaguardDataContext(); Line 88:
>   dbRetaguard.USERS_MODULOs.InsertOnSubmit(modulo); Line 89:
>   try Line 90:             {
>
> Source File:
>   c:\SOURCESAFE\Projetos\EMS\EMS.Dados\Controles\PermissoesLinxDB.cs
>   Line: 88
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NotSupportedException: An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an
>   entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another
>   DataContext.  This is not supported.]
>   System.Data.Linq.StandardChangeTracker.Track(MetaType mt, Object obj,
>   Dictionary`2 visited, Boolean recurse, Int32 level) +891018
>
>   System.Data.Linq.StandardChangeTracker.Track(Object obj, Boolean
>   recurse) +83    System.Data.Linq.StandardChangeTracker.Track(Object
>   obj) +12    System.Data.Linq.Table`1.InsertOnSubmit(TEntity entity)
>   +172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `_modulo` and `modulo` are the SAME object.  Both variables reference the same object.

What you are doing right now with `_modulo = modulo;` is NOT copying `modulo` to the new object but instead setting the reference for `_modulo` to the exact same point in memory of `modulo`. References are equal.

Then, when you call `_PermissoesLinxDB.SalvaModulosUser(_modulo);` it is actually trying to save(?) the already existing object, `modulo` and throwing an exception because it already exists.

What I think you intend to do is something like the following which is to 1) create a new object, 2) assign the internal values of another object to it, and finally 3) save the new object:

```
USERS_MODULO _modulo = new USERS_MODULO();
// assign each property from the old object to this brand new object
_modulo.PropertyA = modulo.PropertyA; // obviously, substitute your property names
_modulo.PropertyB = modulo.PropertyB;
_modulo.PropertyC = modulo.PropertyC;
// etc..
```